# IDENTITY_INSERT SQL script

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-scripts, management-studio-express

**Situation**

I have a SQL script that I need to push some basic data to my database. Therefore I use the following script (and others). I want to provide manually an primary key for the rows I manually create.

**Problem**

If I execute the script it will say that I need to enable IDENTITY_INSERT. I added this row `SET IDENTITY_INSERT UserGroups ON;` as many examples use but it still will give the same error when I have added it.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT UserGroups ON;  
GO 

INSERT INTO UserGroups VALUES (0, 0);
```

Error when running script:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'UserGroups' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

**Question**

Do I need to change something in my database as well or is there something else what I forget in the script to add manually a primary key?

**Details**

I use SQL Server 2016 Management Studio.

I use DDL Script for SQL scripts

I work with Entity Framework.

I got two columns in this table

1. Primary key: Id
2. int: GroupHeadId

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error states, you need a column list.

```
INSERT INTO UserGroups (Id, GroupHeadId)
VALUES (0,0)
```

Answer (score 7):

The error message is telling you the problem.

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'UserGroups' can only be specified when **a column list is used** and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

You're not using a column list. Specify the columns.

Comment: The both are good anwers I chose to accept the other one because that was code that I could paste and what worked directly. If I could I would accept this one as well :}.